# Why wouldn't this pointer operation work?

Tags: c, pointers

So I have an array of linked lists

```
node* x = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node) * 500);
```

Now I want to insert into this list

```
int value;
value = 50;
node* ins;
ins = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
ins->val = value;
ins->next = &x[20];
&x[20] = ins;
```

Error i'm getting; 1value required as left operand of assignment

Incase you want to see the node struct

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
 } node;
```

Why wouldn't something like this work? I want to learn :D

Edit: The error is pointed to this line

```
&x[20] = ins;
```

Comment: Mandatory reading regarding [casting malloc's return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: `&x[20] = ins;` what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: In the future, copy and paste errors via the clipboard. The term is `lvalue`, not `1value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that when you write `&x[20]`, you are getting back the address of the 20th element of the array `x`. Once you've created the array `x`, you can't change where its elements appear in memory. You can change the *contents* of the array elements, but *where those elements are* isn't going to change. As a result, writing `&x[20] = ins` is illegal, since the most natural interpretation of this statement is "move the 20th element of `x` to the spot pointed at by `ins`."

On the other hand, the code `x[20] = ins` is better (but it still has an issue). That means "change the *contents* of the 20th element of the array `x` to hold the address stored in `ins`." Keep in mind that there's a difference between "the address *stored in* `x[20]`" (which is given by `x[20]`) and "the address *of* `x[20]`," which is given by (`&x[20]`).

The problem with that line of code is that `x[20]` has type `node` and `ins` has type `node*`. Did you mean to make `x` a `node**` (a pointer to an array of `node*`s? If you make that change, that line should compile.

Technically speaking, the issue here is that the address-of operator returns an *rvalue*, but you can only put *lvalues* on the left-hand side of an assignment statement. An rvalue is a value like 137 or "hello" that represents, in some sense, a "pure value" that isn't the name of some place you can put something. Writing something like `137 = x` isn't legal because you can't store `x` "in" 137, the same way that writing `&x[20] = ins` isn't legal because you can't store `ins` "in" `&x[20]`.

Comment: Downvoter - can you explain what's wrong with this answer and how you can improve it.

Comment: The issue is with trying to write to an `rvalue`, it is the same error as `1 + 1 = (int)x`

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, absolutely. But I figured that I'd explain *why* the address is an rvalue and why trying to assign it here isn't meaningful.

Comment: That particular tangent doesn't explain the problem, it has nothing to do with the "where those elements are isn't going to change".

Comment: And I feel it's misleading to the OP to even attempt and give a "natural" interpretation to `&x[20] = ins`

Comment: I removed my downvote since the third paragraph you added is spot on, but my previous comments about the first still stand.

Comment: the code x[20] = ins is totally fine. Is it really fine?

Comment: @KooroshHajiani I believe so - am I missing something?

Comment: You are assigning a pointer to node to node, are they not incompatible?

Comment: @KooroshHajiani Oh whoops, I didn't think to check the types. Let me go and fix that...

Answer (score 1):

i am guessing that `x` is an array of pointers to nodes. SO do

```
node** x = (node**) malloc(sizeof(node*) * 500);
```

You then want to store the address of your new node in a free slot of x

```
x[20] = ins;
```

although I am not sure where the 20 comes from

Your original construction

```
&x[20] = ins;
```

simply doesnt make sense , you are trying to change the address of an array member, not allowed

Comment: 20 Would just be a random index i chose to append to

Comment: Why would you guess that when the OP specified it's an array of objects?

Comment: cos he tries to store the address of a node in it

Comment: If `x` is of type `node*`, isn't `x[20]` a `node` then?

Answer (score 1):

It is not 1value, it is lvalue, L as in LOVE.

```
&x[20] = ins;
```

says, approximately, take the 20th element in the array x.  Find its address, change it.  You can never change a pointer, you can only change the value that pointer is pointing to.  So lvalue (an expression appearing on the left of assignment) can only be something like *node, but not &node.
You don't need to allocate ans again.  You already have a bunch of node objects allocated.  You can just do

```
x[20].val = value;
```

Probably that's not what you want.  But then then you can just change your x to be an array of pointers to node objects:

```
node** x = (node**) malloc(sizeof(node*) * 500);
```

then do

```
   x[20] = ins;
```

Comment: L as in LEFT / R as in RIGHT would perhaps be slightly more pedagogical :) Although you wrote it's the expression appearing on the left.

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely one cool way of doing it. So if I just want an array of linked lists, why an array of pointers? This definitely seems like it would make it much much easier